# c# Windows Media Playback Component freezes

Tags: c#

Im developing a Video player in c# win10 .NET 4.6 and it randomly freezes on loop on multiple machines. Memory & CPU does not increase.

I have to trigger the exact millisecond when the loop has to be triggered so setmode loop true is only a fallback option. Currently im setting currentposition to 0 with a very pecise Timer and it works great until it freezes without any error message. I tried all methods i could find to catch the error wo success..

This is my first post here so please excuse my formatting. 
The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.enableContextMenu = false;
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.CausesValidation = false;
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlenabled = false; 
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("loop", true); // Fallback loop if Timer fails
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.windowlessVideo = true;
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.stretchToFit = true;
//axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange += OnPlayerStateChange;
//axWindowsMediaPlayer1.MediaError += OnPlayerMediaError;
//axWindowsMediaPlayer1.ErrorEvent += new EventHandler(OnPlayerErrorEvent);
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = (string)local["target"];

private void OnMultimediaTimer(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 0;
}
```

I was searching alot but can't find any solution to this. 
Thx

Comment: Windows Event Viewer says nothing special:

Comment: The program VION.exe version 1.0.0.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
 Process ID: 2bc4
 Start Time: 01d454d98629a5fa
 Termination Time: 5
 Application Path: C:\Users\DEXTER\Desktop\VION\VION\bin\Release\VION.exe
 Report Id: ded19570-2797-4143-b201-55123c7680bc
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Fault bucket 1735151935626388244, type 5
Event Name: AppHangB1
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: VION.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 5baa40fc
P4: 3ed0
P5: 134217985
P6: 
P7: 
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: ded19570-2797-4143-b201-55123c7680bc
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: 510e49752ef4cdfea8147f7e0257a314